# When operating system is installed on ARM board ? Calling the address of port will map to real address or virtual address?

Tags: c, linux, arm, kernel, embedded

I am planning to put OS on my ARM board to get extra facility like memory management , File system etc..
For example if I want want to write a value to port x to blink led I can write (int*)0x00458=1 without OS . But if with OS if I write the same (int*)0x00458=1 .
The memory will be of user space virtual memory or real memory address .
Sorry I don't know how to express my question pardon me for that .
My goal is to put OS on my ARM board and write LED blink program with out using driver library.

Comment: If you enabled the MMU, you need to map the physical page on which 0x00458 is located into the address space of the program you want to use the LED from. Then you can make the LED blink as you like.

Comment: @Bhav also note that device I/O isn't usually allowed for user-mode applications by most OSes, you may need to write a kernel driver/module to expose an interface to user mode applications

Comment: @FUZxxl If you know any links to learn on how to do these kind of stuffs can you please share. Thanks in advance

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Then how these real time applications runs with RTOS .Will I get any ready made drivers ?

Comment: Which OS are you putting on the board?

Comment: All depends on which type of ARM (M, A) and what is the OS you want to use.

Comment: @BhavithCAcharya Questions asking for links to off-site resources are off topic on Stack Overflow. That said, try http://wiki.osdev.org.

Comment: Virtual memory is achieved through the MMU hardware and not by some OS. As for the case of a RTOS, its purpose is to provide a scheduler, the possibility to run multiple processes with individual stacks and to set priorities between them etc. It is not going to provide you with drivers for miscellaneous MCU hardware. Perhaps the specific RTOS port will configure the MMU for you out of necessity, as a side effect. If you want to use something far more bloated like Linux, then that's a whole different story.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the os, with linux you can use mmap to ask the operating system to map you a hole, with permissions, to punch through from the application layer to that physical address.

Windows there was the giveio thing for I/O, and likely a way to write a kernel driver for punching through with memory mapped I/O.

It is heavily operating system dependent so you have look at your operating system.  You tagged linux so start with mmap, there should already be some examples of how to do this in stackoverflow answers.  As well as elsewhere, only takes a few lines of code to get the pointer (note  asking for a larger space like 0x10000000 bytes is more likely to get a pointer than 0x1000 bytes for example).

Comment: Yes the address is virtual, the operating system (certainly linux and windows) use the mmu, so you will get a virtual address that is mapped to your desired physical address with your permissions on it.   Note if your thing is at 0x12345678, as mmap for 0x10000000 with a size of say 0x10000000 then access the returned pointer+0x02345678, dont ask for 0x12345678 and dont ask for 4 bytes worth.

Comment: I have used this approach countless times.

Answer (score 0):

since you want to write 1 to memory this   (int*)0x00458=1  is incorrect.

you must use

```
*(volatile int*)0x00458=1
```

to write in memory:
use volatile to prevent compiler from optimizing your code out.

this used to blibk a LED on port address 0x65 for example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
while (1)
{
    //PORTG^=1;
    *(volatile uint32_t*)0x65 ^= 1;
    //delay
}
```

this instruction will compile to correct assembly code, no matter there is OS or not.
the only note for os is:
if your ARM CPU hase remapping for address you must find new address, again this instruction will be correct. for details about your os, you may read os documentation.
Hope this helps.